# Is $\frac{1}{x}$ on [0,$\infty$] continuous at zero?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

Taking the definition of continuity, two of three conditions are met, i.e.

a) We would have to define $f(0)=\infty$, but normally division by zero is not well-defined.

b) The limit $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$ exists.

c) The value of the limit equals the value $f(0)$.

Questions:

1) I that correct?

2) Does anything change if $f(x)=x^2$, or if we take $$\frac{1}{|x|} \text{ or } \frac{1}{x^2}$$ on the domain $[-\infty,\infty]$?

3) As for the participating notions that are needed to come to an answer, are there any common definitions which would lead to another conclusion? Something like "we say that a limit exists if its value is a finite number" etc.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but how is $1/|x|$ defined at $x=0$? I suppose you could think of it has being continuous in the _extended_ sense, as in we consider our realm of numbers to be the reals along with $-\infty$ and $\infty$. Then you could declare $1/|0|=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}1/|x|=\infty$, so it's consistent. Note this falls apart if you try just $1/x$.

Comment: I would not agree that either of the conditions (a) or (b) is met; and (c) is meaningless, since neither value is defined.

Comment: What the heck?! How is $\frac{1}{0}$ even defined?!

Comment: b) is wrong as well, $\infty$ is not a limit

Comment: @Blake : it's not clear, but it seems the OP is defining a function at value in $[0,+\infty]$. For the OP : About the continuity, you need to define properly the topology you put on $[0,+\infty]$

Comment: @Tryss I'm not very confident in my topology, but I believe under the topology of the [extended real number line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) (link for OP), it should be continuous. The page also talks a little about what OP is suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you equip $\mathbb R\cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$ with the right topology (namely such that the $(a,\infty]$ with $a\in\mathbb R$ are open neighbourhoods of $+\infty$), then your eextension of $x\mapsto \frac1x$ to the interval $[0,\infty]$ by letting $f(0)=\infty$ and $f(\infty)=0$ is indeed continuous. The coninuoty at $x=0$ is precisely a rephrasing of the statement that $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1x=+\infty$ (i.e., that for any $a\in\mathbb R$ we find $\delta >0$ such that $\frac1x>a$ for all $x$ with $0<x<\delta$).

The same works (with the same argument) with the obvious extensions of $x\mapsto \frac1{|x|}$ or $x\mapsto \frac1{x^2}$.

You *could* make it work with $x\mapsto \frac1x$ on all of $\mathbb R$ if you used the *one-point* compactification of $\mathbb R$ instad of the two-point compactification above. In it, neighbourhoods of $\infty$ contain both all large positive and small negative numbers. Visually, you bend $\mathbb R$ to a cicle and close the gap with a single point.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue at least b) is wrong. "$\lim f(a) = \infty$" is just a shorthand people use to mean "the limit is undefined" (at least in my experience).

Comment: So there is no difference between $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x \sin x$?

Comment: No, that is not true. It implies, that "the limit is undefined", but it's a stronger statement; see Ant's answer.

Comment: I understand the objection; all I would say though is that both of those limits are undefined, but not both of them would have "$\lim f = \infty$". I mean to say $P \rightarrow Q$ does not imply $Q \rightarrow P$.

Comment: Writing $\lim{x \to \infty} x \sin x = \infty$ would be wrong according to the definition I was taught (and that I reported in my post). Why should be lose information and say that the limit is undefined when we have a pretty good idea of how the function behaves? (in the case of $f(x) = x$, for example)

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "does not exist" for "is undefined".

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand people that say that conditions b) is wrong. Are you telling me that you don't know the difference between a function that admits no limit like $x \sin x$ and one that just grows without limit? (like $x$? )

$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = + \infty$ means that $$\forall N > 0\  \exists \delta > 0 : |x-c|<\delta \implies f(x) > N$$

So I would argue that conditions b) is met. The point is that the function is *not* defined at $x=0$, and there is no point saying that in that point it equals $\infty$ as $\infty$ is *not* a number.

The correct way to think about it is with the limit definition.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: The function is defined at $x=0$. The OP defined it. The question is whether it becomes continuous after this definition.

Comment: In at least some (most?) ways of introducing the concept of limits, $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = +\infty$ means the limit does not exist for the reason that the function is always greater than any proposed limit in some neighborhood of $c$, as opposed to any of the other reasons a limit might not exist. It has been pointed out that you can define a topology on the extended reals that makes this limit defined, but that's not the first thing people will necessarily think to do.

Comment: Your definition of the limit is wrong.

Comment: @MattSamuel The OP didn't specify it at first (edited later) And if I see someone defining a function in a point to be $\infty$ without first defining what the point $\infty$ is (and therefore the extended topology) I will assume they don't know about this and that they think $\infty$ is a number and you can work with that. That is why I answered the way I did. :-)

Comment: @DavidK That was precisely the point of my answer :-)

Comment: @SebastianBechtel You're a little bit blunt. I have been taught so in one of Italy's best universities so I am sure this is standard, at least in Italy. In english speaking countries it may be different but that would surprise me as usually mathematical notation is pretty consistent across countries.

Comment: @Ant Ok, then I choose $\delta = 0$ and the limit of all functions in all points is $+\infty$. And then I consider a function $f$ on $(0,1]$ and define $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ for $x\in (\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac 1 n]$ for even $n$ and $f(x)=-\frac 1 x$ for $x\in (\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac 1 n]$ for odd $n$. Then the limit in $0$ is clearly $+\infty$ ;)

Comment: @Ant There is a question of whether a limit has to be a number in order to exist. The way I've seen limits taught in introductory calculus, $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = 3$ describes a limit at $c$, whereas $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = +\infty$ merely describes a behavior of a function that has no limit at $c$.

Comment: @SebastianBechtel Okay I wasn't being rigorous as I just wanted to pass the message. Of course we require $\delta > 0$ and the absolute value is wrong (it slipped in! ) Also it only works if $c \in \mathbb R$ and I should add that we don't care about what happens in $x=c$, but as I said I wasn't really trying to be rigorous. Don't be pedantic! :-P

Comment: @DavidK Then apparently there *is* some difference in notation because the way I was taught $\lim f = \infty$ has a very precise meaning, and if a limit does not exists (meaning for example that the function oscillates between two values) then we say so. :-)

Comment: @Ant $\lim f = +\infty$ _does_ have a very precise meaning. We're just arguing about very fine points of how to express that meaning in words. You say "the limit is infinity", some others say "$f$ goes to infinity." Also keep in mind I'm getting the latter definition from some introductory calculus courses; you can certainly make other definitions, especially in other contexts.